# Displaying proper validation messages

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play Framework 1.2.5 with Java. I have a login form. I am trying to validate the login form with an required check i.e. both the username and password are required. I did this code:

```
 public static void welcome(@Required String txtUserName, @Required String txtPassword){
    if(Validation.hasErrors()){
        flash.error("Oops!!! Please enter your credentials!");
        login();
    }       
    render(txtUserName,txtPassword);
}
```

For displaying the messages, this is what I have in the heml page:

```
<td align="right">
#{if flash.error}
<p style="color: red;">
    ${ flash.error }
</p>
#{/if}
</td>
```

If any one or both of them is absent then I want to display specific messages i.e. If User Name is absent then the message should be "Please provide a User Name!!!". Presently, it is displaying a common message.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Validation class has a method hasError:

```
/**
 * @param field The field name
 * @return True is there are errors related to this field
 */
public static boolean hasError(String field) {
    return error(field) != null;
}
```

Try to use this method like this:

```
if(validation.hasError("name_of_username_form_field")){
    flash.error("Username required");
    login();
}else if (validation.hasError("name_of_password_form_field")){
    flash.error("Password required");
    login();
}
```

The field name must match the name of the one of the input element in your groovy template.

Good luck!